# How to find connected triangles on a 3d mesh

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, mesh

I have a file exported from a 3d application like Blender or Maya. I am able to read the files. I end up with indices describing each triangle and a vertex list.

The file can have more than one connected mesh, two spheres for example. I want to select individual meshes by finding connected triangles. What is the best way to do this? What geometric algorithms can I use? Any examples?  Can it be multi threaded?

Comment: This is probably better accomplished by making the meshes separate nodes in the scene graph and not flattening the whole scene into one node at export time.

Comment: True. But I can't guarantee that though, because I cannot author all the files. All I can do is extract the information. 3d packages have a connectred or linked selection command. I'm wondering how they do it.

Comment: By connected do you mean sharing at least on vertex or intersecting? If its the first, generate adjacency information for each vertex (use hashing?) and then do a traversal starting from an arbitrary vertex, marking verts as visited.

Comment: Yes connected by at least one vertex. Thanks I will try that. Is there any literature on this subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a graph solution.

Take all the data, the vertices become nodes in the graph, the edges linking vertices, link the nodes in the graph. Run a DSF/BFS on it marking all the nodes that you visit. All the nodes marked belong to the same object.

Run it again starting from an unmarked nodes to find additional objects.

You can construct a graph in parallel if you think it's easier, but you should be able to do it with the geometrical data as well.

Answer (score 0):

A graph solution indeed, but with triangles as nodes and adjacent edges as connections between nodes. This can then be solved as a [max clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Comment: Short answers with an external url are discouraged, as the external link can change. Please ensure the key details are included in your post.